# 2-D array of Cards (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to make a card trick, and I need to output a table of cards for the User to see. I know i have to use a 2D array for this, but I dont know how to go about doing it.

Right now I have my deck class that is made up of an array of Cards and shuffles the cards into a random order.

```
public class Deck { 
   private Card[] deck;
   private int currentCard;

   public Deck(){
       String[] Faces = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",    "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"};
   String[] Suits = {"Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts"};

   deck = new Card [52];
   currentCard = 0;

   for (int suit = 0; suit < 4; suit++)
   {
       for (int face = 0; face < 13; face++){


           deck [(face + (suit*13))] = new Card(Suits[suit],Faces[face]);
       }
   }
   }

   public void shuffle(){
   currentCard = 0;

   SecureRandom randomNumber = new SecureRandom();

           for (int first = 0; first < deck.length; first++){
               int second = randomNumber.nextInt(52);

               Card temp = deck [first];

               deck[first] = deck [second];
               deck[second] = temp;
           }
}



   public void displayDeck(){
   for (Card card : deck)
       System.out.println(card);
   }
     public static void main (String[]args) {
    Deck theDeck = new Deck(); 
    theDeck.shuffle();
    theDeck.displayDeck();
 }
}
```

I would like to display the cards in a table format like so:

2 hearts     7 diamonds      3 hearts

6 clubs      K diamonds      J spades

k spades     2 clubs         Q hearts

Edit: the above table is just an example, didn't want to output all of the 52 cards

Comment: You should be using `enum`s for the rank and suit.

Comment: I would like to just stick to arrays for this.

Comment: Your deck has 52 cards. Your example output has 9. How do you choose these 9 cards? And what have you tried? What's the concrete problem you're facing?

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear, just didnt want to type out all of the cards. The problem i am facing is that i dont know how to put the cards into a table format using 2d arrays